# c++ map<string,string>::find seems to return garbage iterator

Tags: c++

`map<string,string>::find` seems to be returning garbage iterator, since i can access neither `my_it->first` nor second (NB: `my_it != my_map.end()` is verified). VC2010 reports a debug error, and looking deeper reveals

```
my_it is (Bad Ptr, Bad Ptr).
```

The 'offending' map is a class attribute, `_match`, shown below in context:

```
class NicePCREMatch
{
private:
    map<string, string, less<string> > _match;

public:
    void addGroup(const string& group_name, const string& value);
    string group(const string& group_name);
};
```

Here is the code that returns elements by key (the commented-out code works fine):

```
string NicePCREMatch::group(const string& group_name)
{
    /*for (map<string, string, less<string> >::iterator j = _match.begin(); j != _match.end(); j++)
    {
        if(!strcmp(j->first.c_str(), group_name.c_str()))
        {
            return j->second;
        }
    }

    throw runtime_error("runtime_error: no such group");*/

    map<string, string, less<string> >::iterator i = _match.find(group_name);

    if (i == _match.end())
    {
        throw runtime_error("runtime_error: no such group");
    }

    return i->second;
}
```

And Here is the code that inserts new elements in the map:

```
void NicePCREMatch::addGroup(const string& group_name, const string& value)
{
    _match.insert(pair<string, string>(group_name, value));
}
```

Another class uses NicePCREMatch as follows:

```
template<class Match_t>
vector<Match_t> NicePCRE<Match_t>::match(const string& buf)
{
[snip]
    Match_t m;
[snip]
    m.addGroup(std::string((const char *)tabptr + 2, name_entry_size - 3), \
                buf.substr(ovector[2*n], ovector[2*n+1] - ovector[2*n]));
[snip]
    addMatch(m);
[snip]
    return _matches;
}
```

Where,

```
template<class Match_t>
void NicePCRE<Match_t>::addMatch(const Match_t& m) 
{ 
    _matches.push_back(m);
}
```

Finally, client code uses NicePCRE class as follows:

```
void test_NicePCRE_email_match(void)
{
    NicePCRE<> npcre;
    npcre.compile("(?P<username>[a-zA-Z]+?)(?:%40|@)(?P<domain>[a-zA-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})");
    vector<NicePCREMatch> matches = npcre.match("toto@yahoo.com");
    assert(!matches.empty());
    assert(!strcmp(matches.begin()->group("username").c_str(), "toto"));
    cout << matches.begin()->group("domain").c_str() << endl;
    assert(!strcmp(matches.begin()->group("domain").c_str(), "yahoo.com"));
}
```

BTW, this --is pretty much-- my main (the oddest TDD ever :) ):

```
int main()
{
    int test_cnt = 0;
    cout << "Running test #" << test_cnt << " .." << endl;
    test_NicePCRE_email_match();
    cout << "OK." << endl << endl;
    test_cnt++;

    SleepEx(5000, 1);

    return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT:**
The following modification (compare with the version above) solved my problem. Viz,

```
void NicePCREMatch::addGroup(const string& group_name, const string& value)
{
    _match.insert(pair<string, string>(group_name.c_str(), value.c_str()));
}
```

Client code (slightly modified) now looks like this:

```
void test_NicePCRE_email_match(void)
{
    NicePCRE<> npcre;
    npcre.compile("(?P<username>[a-zA-Z]+?)(?:%40|@)(?P<domain>[a-zA-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})");
    vector<NicePCREMatch> matches = npcre.match("toto@yahoo.com");
    assert(!matches.empty());
    try
    {
        assert(!strcmp(matches.begin()->group("username").c_str(), "toto"));
        assert(!strcmp(matches.begin()->group("domain").c_str(), "yahoo.com"));
        cout << "username = " << matches.begin()->group("username") << endl;
        cout << "domain = " << matches.begin()->group("domain") << endl;
    }
    catch (const runtime_error& e)
    {
        cout << "Caught: " << e.what() << endl;
        assert(0x0);
    }
}
```

This is quite bizarre. Can someone please explain. However, I consider my problem solved already.

Thanks every one.

Comment: Is it possible that `_match` is concurrently modified by another thread? This kind of error could also be cause by memory-corruption elsewhere in your thread.

Comment: Thanks for acting Bjorn Pollex. No, the _match map is accessed only by a single thread. BTW, if it were due to memory-corruption by other thread (or some other thread-unsafety stuff), how do I explain that the commented-out code works but no the one with the map::find call?).

Comment: what's the need of comparison specification (`less<string>`) in `map<string, string, less<string> >`?

Comment: No need --yet. But I don't see the offence it might cause. Or is there?

Comment: You can also check has your NicePCREMatch object gone out of scope or got deleted before you access group() method. Sometimes we localize the problem too deep into the method

Comment: That's not an "attribute" (which is something else). It's a data member.

Comment: @user1080358: Because perhaps the corruption is only affecting the find...?

Comment: Create test project with problem class, test it and attach here if problem appears. I have no errors with similar code (copy-paste your class and implement main).

Comment: Hi all. Thanks for your replies. I've edited my question post. Unni and LRO please can you check if this provides you more info that can point to the may-be corruption. LRO have a say on that (If it's not asking too much), and then I'll try the test project stuff.

Comment: Hi. Torsten, I'll be doing test project stuff soon. But can you have a say on my last edits (more info to help capture the problem).

Comment: Hi all. Yes (LRO), it seems "the corruption is only affecting the find". For, in method `string NicePCREMatch::group` above, the commented-out code works fine, but the not-commented-out code that issues the find(..) call screws. It may thus be worthwhile to look for the problem around the find(..) call in the `string NicePCREMatch::group` class method. Any ideas ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is here

```
if (i == _match.end())
{
    throw runtime_error("runtime_error: no such group");
}

return i->second;
```

Your find failed for some reason. I can't say why because I don't have the full code. But, after the failure, you are throwing an error, but there is nobody to catch outside. Please add a try catch at the point where you call the method group() and implement the logic if the match is not found.
I tried with your sample snippets (+ some changes to get the stuff compiled) and it looks like visual studio continues with the next line in the function even after a throw statement. I don't know the theory behind it. I was bit surprised at seeing such a behavior.

[To make sure that your class structure is not causing the problem, I tried with a simple global method and even the method also gave me the same behavior. If there are somebody who can explain this please feel free.]

Comment: Hi Unni. 

- Indeed `runtime_error("runtime_error: no such group")` was been thrown in class method `string NicePCREMatch::group` but no been caught in my `void test_NicePCRE_email_match` 'test case'. But, for some strange reason VS2010 was not reporting the runtime_error as such (It would give me the misleading Bad Ptr error stuff). I try-catch logic in void `test_NicePCRE_email_match` and caught runtime_error("runtime_error: no such group")`. 

- I'm confident in my (not shown) vector<Match_t> NicePCRE<Match_t>::match` heuristic, so why does the find(..) fail? The answer's in my edit. Thanks

Comment: Are you saying that, after changing  "_match.insert(pair<string, string>(group_name.c_str(), value.c_str()));" the find started giving a valid iterator?

Comment: Thanks once more @Unni. BTW, did someone down-click/vote you? Why? Or am I missing something here? In case yes, how I wish I had sufficient reputation to revoke that right away :) .

Comment: never mind, life is like that :-) you can accept as answer ;-)

Comment: Yes, after changing 
`_match.insert(pair<string, string>(group_name, value)` to `_match.insert(pair<string, string>(group_name.c_str(), value.c_str()))` the find started giving a valid iterator.

Comment: Thanks. However, I find that bit strange. In my prototype I tried adding known key-values in the map and find was working just as expected (without your change). I just tried calling with a non-existing key and that is when I got the 'strange' behaviour of the run-time exception and that is why I wrote the above explanation. So, for me still it is unexplained why it works with an additional .c_str() call.

Answer (score 0):

This might be caused by three things - either you modify the map in some way after the execution of find or you have a memory coruption somewhere in your program or the debugger is simply not showing the correct values for the iterator.

Try using debug output - if the code crashes when you try to output the values, then probably the iterator is really broken.

Also make sure you do not modify the map after the execution of find. If you do, this may make the iterator invalid and so you need to move the find call immedietly before using the iterator.

If both of the above options don't help you probably have memory corruption somewhere and you need to find it. Maybe use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) for that. Please note this should be your last resort only when the two other options are proved impossible.

Comment: `valgrind` should **not** be your "last resort". _Far from it_.

Comment: I meant that it requires a lot of effort to run, not that it will not do the job. Checking if we have case 1 or case 2 will take way less time and that is why I said you one should use valgrind only once he have ruled out the other options.

Comment: That's nonsense. `$ valgrind myApp` is really very easy to type, and you should be doing it as a matter of course in your development process _anyway_; it's far more efficient and effective than spending half a day scattering debug lines throughout your code and then the evening analysing their output.

Comment: Apparantly our experience in using valgrind is quite different. If you develop a huge application that usually takes about 10 mins to load and requires 30 GB of RAM starting valgrind is not "just typing valgrind myApp", but requires a few hours. In the meantime adding debug output if you have good enough knowledge of where and how can save you that time.

Comment: Something is very, _very_ wrong if that's the case. Does your application require a Cray supercomputer? Even if it does, the OP's most certainly does not. A typical valgrind run is a ten-second launch and a coffee break whilst you wait for results.